# Call button's onClick(...) callback regardless of MotionEvent target

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am struggling to implement the following functionality:

There are N buttons in my ViewGroup.

```
------------
| button 1 |
------------
| button 2 |
------------
|   ...    |
------------
| button N |
------------
```

User pushes `button 1` (`MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`) then he moves his finger to `button N` (`MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`) and then he releases his finger (`MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`).

1. I want to highlight any button over which user is moving his finger
   (highlight on hover)
2. I want `onClick(...)` callback of `button N` to be called when user releases his finger on `button N`

I tried to set `onTouchListener` to each button and it seems that the button which is touched first receives all 3 mentioned actions (`MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`).

I also thought of implementing the functionality by overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` method of buttons' parent `ViewGroup`. This would probably be possible, however there doesn't seem to be a way to detect child view from `MotionEvent` passed to `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` method.

Have you any hint for implementation of described functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted to implement is in fact a kind of "Pie Menu" or "Radial Menu" using standard widgets (e.g. Button). I failed to implement it using standard widgets so I implemented the behavior on my own. Here is an inspiration if somebody needs similar feature: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2.2_r1/com/android/camera/ui/PieRenderer.java. The code in link is the one from Google's Camera app since it uses "radial menu" to control camera settings.